# Contrast problem while converting nii to png

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, png

I'm trying to convert nii file to png files, but I need more contrasted png.
Is there a way to do this?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import os    # Traverse folders 
import nibabel as nib #nii Format 1 This bag will be used in general 
import imageio   # Convert to an image 

def nii_to_image(file, pos, mode):
    patient_name = file.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    if mode == 'mask':
        save_to = 'dataset/Сегментация артерии/МАСКА/png/' + patient_name
    if mode == 'ct':
        save_to = 'dataset/Сегментация артерии/КТ/png/' + patient_name
    if not os.path.exists(save_to):
        os.mkdir(save_to)    # New Folder 
    img = nib.load(file)    # Read nii
    img_fdata = img.get_fdata()
    # Contrast
    if mode == 'ct':
        img_fdata = img_fdata - np.min(img_fdata)
        img_fdata = (img_fdata/np.max(img_fdata)) * 255   
    # Start converting to an image 
    (x,y,z) = img.shape
    for i in range(z):      #z Is a sequence of images 
        if pos == 'ax':
            silce = img_fdata[:, :, i]   # You can choose which direction of slice 
        imageio.imwrite(os.path.join(save_to,'{}.png'.format(i)), silce)
        # Save an image
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
def change_contrast(img, brightness, contrast):
    img = np.int16(img)
    img = img * (contrast/127+1) - contrast + brightness
    img = np.clip(img, 0, 255)
    img = np.uint8(img)
    return img

contrasted = change_contrast(img=img, brightness=-160, contrast=600)
```